# Прописать маршрут через IP адрес который не в моей подсети

Tags: linux, iptables, route

Есть два сервера. Основной (Gentoo) и вспомогательный (виртуальный/Centos). Основной имеет IP внешний A.A.A.A, вспомогательный имеет внешний IP B.B.B.B
На вспомогательном поднят VPN IPSEC с поставщиком услуг. С вспомогательного идёт подключение по VPN к 172.16.110.1.

Надо с основного подключиться к 172.16.110.1

На вспомогательном был поднят OpenVPN клиент, который подключался к моему основному серверу + прописано правило
`-A POSTROUTING -s ВПН_ИП_ОСНОВНОГО/32 -d 172.16.110.1/32 -j SNAT --to-source B.B.B.B`
На основном я прописывыл
`route add 172.16.110.1/32 gw ВПН_ИП_ВСПОМОГАТЕЛЬНОГО`

Все хорошо, только впн лёг по независимым от меня причинам и нельзя пока поднять (просьба пока не спрашивать про это).

И вот я пытаюсь сделать проброс без впн
`route add 172.16.110.1/32 gw B.B.B.B`
А на вспомогательном думал прописать
`-A POSTROUTING -s A.A.A.A/32 -d 172.16.110.1/32 -j SNAT --to-source B.B.B.B`

Но при добавлении
`route add 172.16.110.1/32 gw B.B.B.B`
выдает ошибку
`SIOCADDRT: Network is unreachable`

насколько я понимаю, я не могу указать в качестве шлюза внешний ип адрес вспомогательного сервера, т.к. он не в подсети основного сервера.

Буду признателен за любую информацию. Спасибо

Comment: Жесть, такое навертел, что сам себя запутал

Comment: *SIOCADDRT: Network is unreachable* — всё верно: так, как вы хотите, сделать просто невозможно. устанавливайте другой туннель, и используйте его. или настраивайте динамическую маршрутизацию. // подробности: в поисковике по ключевым фразам.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin и другие, это возможно. Читайте документацию на _ip_.

Answer (score 1):

Может кому понадобится.

Решился через iptables вопрос.

eth0 - интерфейс внешнего IP адреса
2222 - порт для подключения к поставщику услуг

На виртуальном сервере:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 40001 -i eth0 -j DNAT --to 172.16.110.1:2222
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 172.16.110.1 --dport 2222 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -p tcp -d 172.16.110.1 --dport 2222 -j MASQUERADE
```